# Numbers for array names run silent with strictures

Tags: perl

Why are array names with numbers treated like predefined globals?

```
perl -Mstrict -wle '@2014 = 3..6; print "@2014"'
```

(no warnings here)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> Perl identifiers that begin with digits, control characters, or
>   punctuation characters are exempt from the effects of the package
>   declaration and are always forced to be in package main ; they are
>   also exempt from strict 'vars' errors.